# Did the ancient Egyptians have a word for "cult"?

Tags: egyptian

The ancient cultures of Greece, Rome, and Egypt did not have a word for religion, at least in our modern understanding of the word. Greece and Rome did have terms for religious practices though, threskeia (θρησκεία) and cultus, respectively. Did the ancient Egyptians have a similar word, or term? I have been unable to find such a word, just the English word "cult" substituted for the Egyptian word.

Comment: Did you find "cult" in something that was supposed to be translated from Ancient Egyptian? Citation.

Answer (score 4):

Several compounds, maybe not in the sense you are looking for:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

if you're looking for a non-compound, probably the closest would be:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: So pairing šmsw with ntrw () would gave a phrase roughly meaning ntrw šmsw, or Netjeru Shemsu?

Comment: It depends what you want to render. Some religions have no gods (e.g. Buddhism, Daoism, Jainism). I would expect not all cults to be theistic as well.

Comment: I am trying to put together a phrase that shows the worship of the Egyptian gods, in ancient Egyptian words. Since there is no word for religion, I am trying to figure out a substitute, that could have reasonably been used. I could just use Kemetic religion, but I want to try and figure out something that sounds cooler and more authentic.